GPS module GY-GPS6MV2 only returns numbers
I have a GY-GPS6MV2 connected to a nano. (Also tried UNO same result). RX on GPS goes to TX of Nano PIN 3 and TX on GPS to PIN 4 on Nano.
When I run the code below all I get is a set of numbers. They do not appear to be hex numbers.
367180827767444486444444444444444444447842535113103671808684714444444444444444447842514813103671807171654444444444444844484844
The code I am using is
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

String data = "";

// Define the Arduino pins for software serial communication
const int RXPin = 4;
const int TXPin = 3;

// Set the default baud rate for the NEO-6M GPS module
const int GPSBaud = 9600;

// Create a software serial object for GPS communication
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup() {
  // Start the hardware serial port for communication with the computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Start the software serial port for GPS communication
  gpsSerial.begin(GPSBaud);
}

void loop() {
  data = "";
  // Check if there is data available from the GPS module
  while (gpsSerial.available()>0) {
    // Read the incoming data and send it to the computer
      data += gpsSerial.read();
  }

    // Read the incoming data and send it to the computer
  Serial.println(data);
  delay(30000);
}

I tried 2 different GPS modules and the result is the same. Seems that the GPS sends me data via the Arduino but not the correct data. I read about cold starts so I left the module running more than 30 hours but the result is the same. I know it may not see satellite and was expecting to see some NMEA from it even if gibberish NMEA.
What have I missed in making this work please?

use a separator when printing values. such as a ,

research ASCII values

Sorry, how does that help turn and ASCII string into NMEA?

it's not an ASCII string ... it is a set of numeric values ... display them as ASCII text, instead of numbers

3671808277674444... is the ASCII code for "$GPRMC,,..., so you are receiving data correctly but doing the wrong data cancatenation. When programming in C/C++, always need to aware what kind of data type you are dealing with. gpsSerial.read() return an int, so you need to cast it to a char before you can concatenate with a String with data += (char) gpsSerial.read();.

@hcheung - Thanks for the help that is exactly what I needed to know. C/C++ is all new to me so I did not know I had to cast the values. Now it is giving characters just got to get the GPS module to see the satellites. I will run it outside today.

When you write gpsSerial.read(), you are calling the method
int SoftwareSerial::read();

Notice it returns an int, not a char. Why, you may ask. The reason
is that a char can only hold 256 different values, whereas this
method can return 257 different values:

values from 0 through 255 represent actual bytes read from the port
the value −1 represents an error condition.

In your case, you don't have to worry about errors, as you are only
calling the method when you know for sure it has data to deliver (i.e.
when gpsSerial.available()>0).
When you write data += gpsSerial.read();, you are calling the method
String & String::operator += (int num);

which appends a number to a string. In the face of it, this seems
meaningless. What could it even mean to “append a number to a string”?
The Arduino library interprets it as meaning “write down the number in
decimal, using ASCII digits, and append that to the string”. Thus, if
you
data += 36;

this will append the string "36" to data.
Now, if you instead do
data += (char) 36,

this will add to data the character number 36, i.e. '$'. And this is
what you actually want. Thus:
data += (char) gpsSerial.read();

